# Using mod_rewrite to 301 redirect get vars to new clean URLs

Tags: regex, apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, get

UPDATE: Solution at bottom.

I recently switched from using a set up such as `index.php?p=page_name&o=temporary_override` and switched to clean urls such as `/page_name/temporary_override`.  The temporary override is just so I can see the results of the site changes while it's being built.

I currently have mod_rewrite set to:

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php?GHPAGE=$1 [L,QSA]
```

Which will capture the "subdirectories" and then PHP parses the URL from the GHPAGE $_GET var.  What I want is to set up a 301 redirect so that anyone using index.php?p=something&o=something_else will get redirected to /something/something_else.  Any idea how I can accomplish this?  The p & o may come in any order and one or the other may not exist.

EDIT: Ok, after help from @Jon-Lin, @dambrisco, and @anubhava, I have gotten closer.  My .htaccess file now looks like:

```
RewriteEngine On
#Base Directory
RewriteBase /test/

#if 2 GET Vars
RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} ^([A-Z]{3,9})\ \/([^\/]+\/)*(index\.php)?\?[op]=([^&]+)&[op]=(.+)\ HTTP\/
RewriteRule ^index\.php$ /%4/%5 [R=301,L]
#if 1 GET Var
RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} ^([A-Z]{3,9})\ \/([^\/]+\/)*(index\.php)?\?[op]=(.+)\ HTTP\/
RewriteRule ^index\.php$ /%4 [R=301,L]
#Remove index.php
RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} ^([A-Z]{3,9})\ \/([^\/]+\/)*index\.php\ HTTP\/
RewriteRule ^index\.php$ / [R=301,L]

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php?GHPAGE=$1 [L,QSA]
```

It is now redirecting, but not quite where it needs to go.  `root/test/index.php?p=test&o=override` now redirects to `root/test/override?p=test&o=override`.  Closer, but I can't figure out how to get rid of the GET vars which are being added to the URL or why it's redirecting to the root directory instead of to the RewriteBase directory.

EDIT:

It's now redirecting properly, but for some reason it's dropping the /test/ RewriteBase folder from the equation.  `http://www.domain.com/test/index.php?p=page1&o=operation` is getting redirected to `http://www.domain.com/page1/operation`.  New .htaccess file is below:

```
RewriteEngine On

RewriteBase /test/

#if 2 GET Vars
RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} ^([A-Z]{3,9})\ /([^/]+/)*(index\.php)?\?[op]=([^&]+)&[op]=(.+)\ HTTP\/
RewriteRule ^ /%4/%5? [R=301,L]

#if 1 GET Var
RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} ^([A-Z]{3,9})\ /([^/]+/)*(index\.php)?\?[op]=(.+)\ HTTP\/
RewriteRule ^ /%4? [R=301,L]

#if index.php
RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} ^([A-Z]{3,9})\ \/([^\/]+\/)*index\.php\ HTTP\/
RewriteRule ^index\.php$ /$ [L,R=301]

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php?GHPAGE=$1 [L,QSA]
```

Thanks everyone.  Question has been solved.  Final .htaccess is below for reference.

```
RewriteEngine On

RewriteBase /test/

#if 2 GET Vars
RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} ^([A-Z]{3,9})\ /([^/]+/)*(index\.php)?\?[op]=([^&]+)&[op]=(.+)\ HTTP\/
RewriteRule ^ %4/%5? [R=301,L]

#if 1 GET Var
RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} ^([A-Z]{3,9})\ /([^/]+/)*(index\.php)?\?[op]=(.+)\ HTTP\/
RewriteRule ^ %4? [R=301,L]

#if index.php
RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} ^([A-Z]{3,9})\ \/([^\/]+\/)*index\.php\ HTTP\/
RewriteRule ^index\.php$ ? [L,R=301]

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php?GHPAGE=$1 [L,QSA]
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add this somewhere in your htaccess:

```
RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} ^([A-Z]{3,9})\ /index\.php\?p=([^&]+)&o=(.+)\ HTTP
RewriteRule index.php /%2/%3 [R=301,L]
```

And if you want to cover the case where there's no "temporary_override", add this too:

```
RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} ^([A-Z]{3,9})\ /index\.php\?p=(.+)\ HTTP
RewriteRule index.php /%2 [R=301,L]
```

---

> Closer, but I can't figure out how to get rid of the GET vars which are being added to the URL or why it's redirecting to the root directory instead of to the RewriteBase directory

Add a `?` at the end of `/%4/%5` to get rid of the query string. And remove the leading `/` from `/%4/%5` to keep it from rewriting to the root. So, for example, one of your rules should look like this:

```
RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} ^([A-Z]{3,9})\ \/([^\/]+\/)*(index\.php)?\?[op]=([^&]+)&[op]=(.+)\ HTTP\/
RewriteRule ^index\.php$ %4/%5? [R=301,L]
```

Comment: You may want to use `RewriteRule ^index/.php$ /%2/%3 [R=301,L]`

Comment: You mean `^index\.php$` - minor nitpick.

Comment: Doesn't seem to do anything.  Currently using the code by @JonLin with @dambrisco's addition to create `RewriteRule ^index\.php$ /%2/%3 [R=301,L]`.  Visiting the site with index.php?p=l&o=override, the site doesn't redirect to /l/override.  Appreciate the help, so far.

Comment: After a little searching and getting an output of what THE_REQUEST returns, it looks like: `GET /test/index.php?p=test&o=override HTTP/1.0`.  So, I understand the `%{THE_REQUEST} ^([A-Z]{3,9})\ `, but this is where I get confused.  Should the '/' in front of index.php be escaped, like `\/index\.php`?  I see cPanel has escaped a bunch of '/' in other 301 redirects for other domains on my server.  Also, `\?p=([^&]+)&o=(.+)\ HTTP`, should that be `\?(p|o)=([^&]+)&(p|o)=(.+)\ HTTP(.{0,4})`?  Would that allow the get variables to go in either order?  Thanks again!

Comment: Awesome, almost there.  I missed the update to this answer.  Now the only issue is `http://www.domain.com/test/index.php` is redirecting to `http://www.domain.com/` instead of `http://www.domain.com/test/`.

Comment: `RewriteRule ^index\.php$ /$ [L,R=301]` should say `RewriteRule ^index\.php$ /test/ [L,R=301]` or `RewriteRule ^index\.php$ ? [L,R=301]`, to reflect the changes (removing the leading slash) to the other rules.

Answer (score 0):

You're going to want to use the following:

```
RewriteRule ^([^/]+)/?$ index.php?p=$1 [L,QSA]
RewriteRule ^([^/]+)/([^/]+)/?$ index.php?p=$1&o=$2 [L,QSA]
```

This way, `example.com/page_name` gets internally passed to `index.php?p=page_name` and `example.com/page_name/operation` gets passed to `index.php?p=page_name&o=operation`. Jon Lin's answer seems to have been doing the opposite, which I hadn't noticed last night.

There shouldn't be any need for any RewriteConds except to avoid conflict with other rules that you might have, just to clarify.

Comment: If I'm reading those correctly, those will only affect properly typed URLs.  What I want to do is 301 redirect the old dirty URLs to the new clean URLs.  As in `/?p=test&o=override` 301=> `/test/override`.

Comment: Ah, my bad. I'd misunderstood the problem. Now Jon Lin's answer makes a lot more sense. I'll take a second look at this later if it hasn't been solved.

Answer (score 0):

Change 2 of your RewriteRule lines should end with `?` like this:

```
#if 2 GET Vars
RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} ^([A-Z]{3,9})\ /([^/]+/)*(index\.php)?\?[op]=([^&]+)&[op]=(.+)\ HTTP\/
RewriteRule ^ /%4/%5? [R=301,L]

#if 1 GET Var
RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} ^([A-Z]{3,9})\ /([^/]+/)*(index\.php)?\?[op]=(.+)\ HTTP\/
RewriteRule ^ /%4? [R=301,L]
```

Comment: Closer, it's sort of working, but now it's changing the URL from `/test/index.php?p=test&o=override` to `/?GHPAGE=test/override`. EDIT: Nevermind, it decided to start playing nice.  It IS still dropping the RewriteBase folder from the equation, though.  `/test/index.php?p=test&o=override` is becoming `root/test/override/` when it should be `root/test/test/override/`.  Any ideas?  I'll update my .htaccess above.